# openvpn subnet conflicts with wifi subnet

Tags: routing, openvpn, wifi, subnet

When using openvpn at home, I have a very simple configuration file because my home subnet uses 192.168.1.*

so when I run openvpn --config client.config
my routing table looks like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.7.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp4s0
10.7.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
[VPN REMOTE]    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 enp4s0
128.0.0.0       10.7.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp4s0
```

I don't know much about routing but it seem that openvpn adds the 10.7.0.1 gateway as some sort of internal subnet. This works fine on a home network, but when I try this at work which uses 10.3.1.X subnet, I am able to establish a connection to the remote, but I do not get access to the internet. I might be wrong but I think it's because it uses the same subnet as the local wifi.

Here is the routing table from work:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.7.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.3.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp4s0
10.7.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
[VPN REMOTE]    10.3.1.1        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 enp4s0
128.0.0.0       10.7.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.3.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp4s0
```

1. is this the conflict or is there something else at play?
2. if this is the conflict, how can I get openvpn to use a different local subnet to not conflict with my local wifi?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me to be a reasonably sane and expected routing table for OpenVPN.

You appear to have `redirect-gateway def1` enabled in your configuration, which means that all traffic goes through the VPN, not just traffic intended for the remote destination. You may want to reconsider this if it's not intended.